# Flutter integration_test - Making screenshot

Tags: flutter, integration-testing

Hey are there any possibilities to make a screenshot when using integration_test lib (https://pub.dev/packages/integration_test) for UI tests?

In flutter_driver it was bulid in method to take it. Here i couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Flutter version 2.5.0 you can take a screenshot by very simple way.
Here is manual about how to do it: https://dev.to/mjablecnik/take-screenshot-during-flutter-integration-tests-435k

Answer (score 5):

I found an open issue on GitHub - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51890

They are working on that capability.

Answer (score 4):

[The flutter integration test example has the skeleton to perform screenshots](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/0504fac7e2bc80a6c44ca7fc556033571860ef4c/packages/integration_test/example)

First create the driver for the integration test

```
//test_driver/foo_test.dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter_driver/flutter_driver.dart';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test_driver_extended.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  final FlutterDriver driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
  await integrationDriver(
    driver: driver,
    onScreenshot: (String screenshotName, List<int> screenshotBytes) async {
      final File image =
          await File(screenshotName).create(recursive: true);
      image.writeAsBytesSync(screenshotBytes);
      return true;
    },
  );
}
```

Then in your test

```
//integration_test/bar_test.dart
void main() {
  final binding = IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()
      as IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding;

  testWidgets('screenshot', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    await binding.convertFlutterSurfaceToImage();
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    await binding.takeScreenshot('screenshots/screenshot.png');
  }
}
```

Then

```
flutter drive --driver=test_driver/foo_test.dart --target integration_test/bar_test.dart
```

Note:

- the screenshot is a png
- You cannot save directly from the test without tweaks (explain the necessity of a driver)

Comment: thanks @UmNyobe, top answer, this works in 2024.  now i can figure out how to generate my screenshots without all those old methods that have been deprecated. 

Comment: aie, but `flutter drive` on the way out?